# Gitlab integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a paid GitLab account where i store my software-project. I have installed Jenkins on my home PC. I have a Jenkins-project configured to build my software-project.

I don't know how to configure Jenkin's and my GitLab account so that Jenkins can 
get the latest source of my software-project from my GitLab account.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I know what to do once the source code is downloaded from GitLab

Regards 
  Juby

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gitlab Jenkins plugin to configure Gitlab in your Jenkins [Gitlab Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitLab+Plugin)

otherwise you can create a jenkins Global Credential
user name : gitlab-ci-token
password : the token of your account you find it in the gitlab :

Profile Settings > Account >  private token